# How to add groovy 3.0.3 as maven dependency in a maven project?

Tags: maven, groovy

I have my current project having groovy version 2.4.7. So i have the below maven dependency in my project

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.7</version>
 </dependency>
```

Now I want to update the groovy version to the latest version ie., 3.0.3. But when I am adding the below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

I am getting the below error:

Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.EvictableCache.getAndPut(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/memoize/MemoizeCache$ValueProvider;)Ljava/lang/Object;

I also see the type is pom here in the new dependency. Could some one please advise what are the steps I need to take in order to update the groovy version in my project?

Thanks,
Sourabh

Comment: I am able to resolve this issue. it was an issue with version conflict because of some other dependencies.

Comment: To clarify again, this is not a valid issue. I experienced this issue as there was some transitive dependency causing the version conflct. I deleted the existing .m2 repo and build the project again and it resolved the issue I was observing.